# response.sendRedirect vs out.println("REDIRECT=SOMEURL")

Tags: servlets, redirect

What is the difference between

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.someurl.com");
```

and

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("REDIRECT=http://www.someurl.com");
```

I know how [`sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) works but what about `out.println("REDIRECT=http://www.someurl.com");` is doing here?

Comment: Where did you read/learn about that?

Comment: I'd been working on a Payment Gateway service in which the response is sent to my servlet. And in my servlet I perform some operation and using `response.sendRedirect()` redirecting to response page, which is not working. While `out.println()` is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'd been working on a Payment Gateway service in which the response is sent to my servlet. And in my servlet I perform some operation and using response.sendRedirect() redirecting to response page, which is not working. While out.println() is working.*

That's then just specific to that service. They apparently require a HTTP 200 response with plain/text content in exactly that format as expected by the specific servcie, instead of a true HTTP [3xx](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) response with a [`Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) header. This way they will in turn take care about the redirect instead of yourself. Basically, the client goes from your server to that payment service and then to the given redirect URL, instead of from your server to the given redirect URL.

It all depends on what the client is expecting. Real clients (web browsers) at least just expect a HTTP 3xx response with a `Location` header in order to perform a redirect.

The following

```
response.sendRedirect("http://example.com");
```

does under the covers effectively the same as

```
response.setStatus(302);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://example.com");
```

Comment: your answer seems promising but how do they come to know about the HTTP response ?

Comment: You just wrote to it? The `out` represents the response body.

Comment: okay. What about the `sendRedirect()`? what would be the response body?

Comment: Nothing. It's empty. Just a `Location` header will be set (as stated in my answer). You can see it in browser's HTTP traffic monitor. Edit: I updated the answer to show the "under the covers" equivalent of `sendRedirect()` which is perhaps more self-explaining (at least, if you're familiar with basic HTTP).

Comment: in my (chrome) browser under network tab I'm getting `Status 200 OK` for both approaches. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nope. Chrome by default starts with a new log on every GET. Enable the "Preserve log" option to tell it to not do that.